# HTML5 Canvas not displaying in browser

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm following [this](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/canvas/notearsgame/#toc-introduction) tutorial to learn HTML5 game development using javascript and jQuery. However, I've already come across a problem. When I run the HTML page that my js file is referenced from, nothing loads, and is just a blank screen. Here is the code for both files. Note that I haven't gotten very far in the tutorial.

index.html

```
<HTML>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<p>HTML5 and jQuery Tests</p>
<script type ="text/javascript" src="test.js"></script>
</body>
</HTML>
```

test.js

```
var CANVAS_WIDTH = 480;
var CANVAS_HEIGHT = 320;

var canvasElement = $("<canvas width='" + CANVAS_WIDTH +"' height='" + CANVAS_HEIGHT +        "'></canvas>");
var canvas = canvasElement.get(0).getContext("2d");
canvasElement.appendTo('body');
var FPS = 30;
setInterval(function() {
update();
draw();
}, 1000/FPS);
function draw() {
canvas.fillStyle = "#000"; 
canvas.fillText("hello.", 50, 50);
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated! Also, am I allowed to ask questions about this code in this forum, on the same thread, or do I have to stat another?

Thanks!
~Carpetfizz

Comment: mention about update() function

Comment: You havnt added any `jquery.js`. But it seems you have added its functionality.

Comment: @silentboy is there anything I have to do to let the browser know that I'm using jquery and not normal javascript? Shouldn't browsers be smart enough to tell the difference?

Comment: I know it is too late but today my hsc exam started. Sorry for late reply but someone has edited his answer and it tell what you needed. However, jquery is a javascript library means that jquery is written with javascript. I think if there a special case exist then a browser may implement it. But all major browser havnt implement it by default. So, if you use prototype.js, jquery.js, dojo, yui etc in your project then you must add that library. So, if the machine arent smart, you have to be. Thanks to all

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't have  an `update` function to call.  When the `setInterval` fires (which is ~32ms after the script loads), you're getting an error.

You need to add jQuery.
It's a library that was written to make working with HTML easier.
It needs to exist ***above*** where `test.js` does.

You can either download your own copy of it, or link to a copy elsewhere on the net - both will work fine.

`$` is used by jQuery as a function to intelligently grab different kinds of items: HTML, JS, etc, and return JS objects with helpful functions for working with whatever you asked for.

Anyway, the `update` would still have caused an error, it was just second in line, behind the missing script.

Comment: ah this makes sense, in the tutorial however, I see no update function at all! could this be a mistake in their editing or is it intentional? also, what would an update() function look like?

Comment: @Carpetfizz the `function update { /*...*/ }` is defined right below the window that has your `setTimeout` listed. It doesn't need to have anything in it, to work right now...  ...it just needs to exist, in order to not crash.  But basically, if you think about a typical videogame, `update` will listen for player movement, will update the positions of everything in "space", figure out score-changes, sync up online stuff, deal damage, award points, figure out if you beat the level, do enemy AI, etc...  `draw` will then paint everything that was repositioned, and texture it and light it, etc...

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but adding "function update() {}" didn't do anything. As an attempt to debug, I just double clicked the ".js" file and got this error from "Windows Script Host": "Line: 4", "Char: 1", Error: "Object expected", Code: "800A138F", Source: "Microsoft JScript runtime error"

Comment: @Carpetfizz You should be debugging inside of either Chrome Developer Tools, Firefox Developer Tools or Firebug. The first two are built into the browsers - personally, I recommend using Chrome for 90% of the debugging/development, and then doing compatibility testing on the others. Double-clicking on it had Windows trying to run the .js file in Windows...

Comment: Ah cool! I did this in Chrome, and got an actual error: Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined

Comment: @Carpetfizz Oh boy. I can't believe I missed this one... Then again, I never, ever use it. See my soon-updated answer.